# Unable to print a pointer after using memcpy

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to get my own version of memcpy to copy a character array from one pointer to another. However, this gives an error. It seems like there is an issue with printf.

Secondly, the official memcpy function returns the destination pointer. Is that really required? If I modify *dest, it should be reflected in *d anyway. So what is the need to return anything?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void memcpy2(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    char *dp = dest;
    const char *sp = src;
    while (n--)
        *dp++ = *sp++;
}

int main(void) {
    char *c = "Hello";
    char *d=NULL;
    memcpy2(d,c,3);
    printf( "%c", *d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: memcpy is a system function.  System functions always need a method to indicate success/failure.  System functions need to have a consistent interface, including the returned value.  For memcpy, returning the destination address on success or returning NULL on failure is how the system function is made consistent with the rest of the systems functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dereference a `NULL` pointer that's undefined behavior, you should allocate space and point to it with `d` in order for that to work, do this, instead of

```
d = NULL
```

write

```
d = malloc(3);
```

and don't forget

```
free(d);
```

after the `printf()`.

If you want to **automagically** make `d` a valid pointer then write `memcpy2()` this way

```
void memcpy2(void **dest, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    *dest = NULL;
    if ((src == NULL) || (n == 0))
        return;
    *dest = malloc(n);
    if (*dest == NULL)
        return;

    char *dp = *dest;
    const char *sp = src;
    while (n--)
        *dp++ = *sp++;
}
```

and then your main would be

```
int main(void) {
    char *c = "Hello";
    char *d = NULL;

    memcpy2(&d, c, 3);
       /*   ^ pass the address of the pointer, so you can change where it points to */

    if (d != NULL) /* prevent NULL dereference. */
    {
        printf("%c", *d);
        free(d);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But it shouldn't be NULL since it goes through memcpy first, and wont that assign "d" a value?

Comment: @sbhatla You have to pass a valid pointer to `memcpy()` pointing to at least as much memory as you request to copy. And the `src` pointer should also meet the same requirements.

Comment: Nice corner case handling in `memcpy2()`.

Comment: memcpy2 will return a NULL pointer for several reasons.  so in main() a NULL pointer needs to be checked for.  NEVER assume a function worked as expected, even your own functions.  And do notice the the memcpy2() function actually checks for errors, rather than blindly assuming everything is corrected and malloc was successful